# Inner Join with Sum in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL and I have two tables, invoice and invoice_item.

invoice:

```
id(pk)  total_invoice_price
1   
2
```

invoice_item:

```
invoice  total_item_price
1        10
1        20
2        25
2        35
```

I need that total_invoice_price be the sum of every total_item_price where invoice = id.

invoice_item.invoice is a fk that references to invoice.id

The best I could make was in the lines of:

```
update(
select invoice.total_invoice_price as old, SUM(invoice_item.total_item_price) as total
from invoice
inner join invoice_item
on invoice.id = invoice_item.invoice
) t 
set t.old = t.total;
```

but it obviously doesn't work.

Tables creation:

```
create table invoice(
  id                number(5)       not null,
  customer_name     varchar2(50)    not null,
  issue_date        date            not null,
  due_date          date            not null,
  comments          varchar2(50)            ,
  total_invoice_price   number(9)               ,
  constraint pk_invoice
  primary key (id)
);

create table invoice_item(
  id                number(5)       not null,
  product_name      varchar2(50)    not null,
  unit_price        number(9)       not null,
  quantity          number(9)       not null,
  total_item_price  number(9)               ,
  invoice           number(5)       not null,
  constraint pk_invoice_item
  primary key (id),
  constraint fk_invoice_item_invoice
  foreign key (invoice)
  references invoice(id)
);
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I expect x to be 30 and y to be 60 there!

Comment: Does the `total_invoice_price` column exist in your table already? What data type is it? It should be NUMBER, but then it couldn't hold `'x'` and `'y'`, so I am confused.

Comment: Aaaah sorry, x and y were just placeholders!!! I'll edit it!

Comment: Better to replace them with NULL, if that's what you really have in the table before the UPDATE.

Comment: @mathguy that column is empty now! I'll change it to null!

Comment: Also add primary key info because to be updatable the query must hold the uniquness. My obvious guess is `Id` is a PK. But this should be stated explicitly.

Comment: @serg - "hold the uniqueness" is correct, but the rest is not. The "uniqueness" that is required is with regard to the source table (the result of aggregation on `invoice_item`), NOT the target table (the one that is being updated). Having PK on `invoice` and FK on `invoice_item` wouldn't help in any way in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Merge`. See below

```
MERGE INTO invoice tb1
     USING (  SELECT invoice, SUM (total_item_price) tot_price
                FROM invoice_item
            GROUP BY invoice) tb2
        ON (tb1.id = tb2.invoice)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET tb1.total_invoice_price = tb2.tot_price;
```

Comment: This will work, but there is no reason to avoid "update through join" (the MERGE statement does exactly the same thing in this case). MERGE is really superior when you must also add rows to the target table when "not matched", and/or delete some of the matched rows. When all that MERGE does is an UPDATE, UPDATE should work just fine by itself.

Comment: @mathguy Agree but what i have seen in most the case we land up the errror which OP faced using joins

Comment: Yes, because people write their queries incorrectly. This OP really pisses me off - I will add a full SQL\*Plus session screenshot to show that the simple `UPDATE` solution I provided is correct.

Comment: @mathguy. I would not use words like `really pisses me off` in any case if my solution is accepted or not. I gave my answer and if worked fine or not should be upto OP.  Its not necessary that everthing we answer is always accepted. Nothing to feel personal.

Comment: @mathguy sorry if I pissed you off, I'm really new to SQL and I'm still having difficulties. Hope you have a good day!

Comment: @XING - I don't care about which solution is accepted or not; and I didn't mean my language to be offensive, I was simply sharing how I feel when people reject correct solutions because they mess them up.

Comment: @mathguy Whatever be the case. I guess if you are so much sensative then this is not the platform to express it. Good day.

Comment: @brightpants - being new to SQL is OK; but I provided an answer, you complained about it throwing an error, I asked you to show exactly the query you used (because IT IS NOT WHAT I WROTE - I just edited my answer to PROVE that), and instead of answering, you simply jumped to a different solution. That is what pissed me off.

Comment: @mathguy The reason why we have mutilple options open for a Question is to look for an alternate if something is not working rather digging the into the solution which is giving error at user end. I see nothing wrong in jumping to another solution

Comment: man I ran EXACTLY the query you sent me, instead of asking maybe for more details or for me to clarify or look for some other errors I might've done you decided to PROVE that your answer was 100% right and accuse me of running it differently. I just ctrl c + ctrl v, it gave me that error which I have no idea why happened! Don't be so agressive, people here are learning, I'm learning, I don't post here that often, I'm not that good with SQL, I'm trying to help you help me by providing as much info as I can.

Comment: @XING - A while back, StackOverflow had a "Documentation" project, they dropped it since. I made only one contribution (which had a very large number of upvotes): I was so mad that people kept saying "Oracle can't do UPDATE through joins" - with exactly the reason you gave in an earlier Comment - that I wrote that Documentation article to show how it is done correctly. Now SO did away with Documentation; and people keep saying what you just said. Which is wrong. (About why such UPDATE can't be done, we must use MERGE, etc.)

Comment: I even upvoted your answer as I could actually understand what you were doing, but it gave me that error message, which I posted here!

Comment: @brightpants - No, that is exactly the problem... I have no issue with marking the MERGE solution as correct, if you had also answered my question. If you copied and pasted my solution, then your tables are not as you presented them. I just showed how the solution works with what you provided, so there is no point in arguing. But - whatever. Have a nice day!

Comment: @mathguy geez, you're the one arguing. They're not exactly like that, they have more columns and more data in them, but the names and everything else is the same!

Comment: @brightpants ... and this is how people end up saying "Oracle can't UPDATE through joins, you must use MERGE". Because they don't do it correctly. That is exactly my point!

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, I said that FOR ME it doesn't work! And I have no idea why! As I said, I ctrl c ctrl v your code, put it into my sqldeveloper and ran it. Throws me that message. Did I do smth wrong creating it? I can even send it to you how I created them if it helps

Comment: @mathguy No one is saying `Oracle can't UPDATE through joins,` atleast one knows oracle will certainly not say. I am not understanding why the discussion is going on. I mean SO says its up to OP to give vote and accept answer bested suited for him. Ideally he shouldnot vote you until his problem should had solved. That was certainly a mistake

Comment: @XING - I think there is some misunderstanding here. I don't care about marks (correct/upvote/downvote), I think the whole system is a bad joke and utterly ridiculous. I do care about trying to help someone, we get to some point - then that person knows what they provided initially is not exactly what they had, the solution I offered fails because of that, but there is no further communication - they jump to something else, they are happy and they leave. Future visitors to this thread see the solution, and the last comment is from the OP saying that it resulted in an Error.

Comment: What would **you** think then? And just search SO to see how many people say Oracle can't update through joins - that was why I wrote the Documentation article in the first place.

Comment: `What would you think then? And just search SO to see how many people say Oracle can't update` - Either they dont know Oracle or are not experienced enough . Thats all i can say. I would say now you have the table definition. Please provide the correct solution for future visitors. Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

```
update
  ( select i.total_invoice_price, x.total_price
    from   invoice i
           join
           (
             select   invoice as id, sum(total_item_price) as total_price
             from     invoice_item
             group by invoice
           ) x
           on i.id = x.id
  )
set total_invoice_price = total_price
;
```

Comments:

You need to aggregate within the second table, before joining. Then you join by id. In this arrangement, you will never run into issues with "uniqueness" or "primary key" being defined; the only condition that matters is that the id be unique in the "other" table, which in this case is the subquery `x`. Since it is an aggregation where you group by id, that uniqueness is guaranteed by the very definition of GROUP BY.

Then: It is unfortunate that you have a table `invoice` and a column (in a different table) also called `invoice`; the invoice id column should be called something like `invoice_id` in both tables. In my subquery, I changed the column name (from the second table) from `invoice` to `id`, by giving it that alias in the `SELECT` clause of the subquery.

**Further comment**: In a comment below this replies, the OP says he ran into an error. That means he didn't use the solution as I wrote it above. Since this is really annoying, I decided to present a full SQL*Plus session to prove that the solution is correct as written.

Create table INVOICE:

```
SQL> create table invoice ( id, total_invoice_price ) as
  2    select 1, cast(null as number) from dual union all
  3    select 2, null from dual;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> select * from invoice;

        ID TOTAL_INVOICE_PRICE
---------- -------------------
         1
         2

2 rows selected.
```

Create table INVOICE_ITEM:

```
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> create table invoice_item ( invoice, total_item_price ) as
  2    select 1, 10 from dual union all
  3    select 1, 20 from dual union all
  4    select 2, 25 from dual union all
  5    select 2, 35 from dual;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> select * from invoice_item;

   INVOICE TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE
---------- ----------------
         1               10
         1               20
         2               25
         2               35

4 rows selected.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

UPDATE statement:

```
SQL> update
  2    ( select i.total_invoice_price, x.total_price
  3      from   invoice i
  4             join
  5             (
  6               select   invoice as id, sum(total_item_price) as total_price
  7               from     invoice_item
  8               group by invoice
  9             ) x
 10             on i.id = x.id
 11    )
 12  set total_invoice_price = total_price
 13  ;

2 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> select * from invoice;

        ID TOTAL_INVOICE_PRICE
---------- -------------------
         1                  30
         2                  60

2 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
```

Clean-up:

```
SQL> drop table invoice purge;

Table dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
SQL> drop table invoice_item purge;

Table dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL>
```

Comment: So, I tried running this and it gives me the following: 

SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

Comment: @brightpants - Then you did not use the solution EXACTLY as written. I tested on my system (by creating the tables and then running the solution exactly as written) and it work perfectly fine. Show the EXACT update statement you ran.

Comment: edited with my table creation. the update statement I ran follows as the exact same!

Comment: @brightpants - Thank you for following up, but I will abandon this thread. I seem to have upset too many people already.

Comment: Because I can totally understand what you were doing, whereas I have much more difficulty getting the merge solution